# How to share data among different Xamarin Forms application on same device?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Form application (support for Android and Windows platform) and I am storing the local data in device cache. I would like to share the same cache data with another Xamarin Form App on the same device.

I have tried to access the same Cache from another app with same Key and same structure but its not possible. I am always return null value when I read the data from another App. I am using the same BlobCache (Akavache)/ Xamarin.Essentials and Preferences class from  Android.Preferences Library.

I have also tried the ISharedPreferences on another test App for shared the data between two app by local device Cache.

How can we share the data with another Xamarin App ? Can anybody share some example ?

Thanks

Susheel

Comment: each app runs in it's own sandbox and does not have access to data belonging to other apps.  This is a basic security feature.

Comment: Hi any other way for share the data among apps?

Comment: [Xamarin Essentials Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share)

Answer (score 0):

As @Jason said is a basic feature to net let you read other app's data installed in the same device.

The suggestion would be to have both of the apps to fetch, update/create the data from the same remote place.